# Correct block diagram of differential equation

Tags: simulation, modeling, simulink, integrator, block-diagram

I am studying modeling and simulation. I have to draw a block diagram (so that it gets simulated in Simulink) of the following differential equation

$$ \frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}=-a_1\frac{d y}{dt}-a_2y+a_2u$$

So my attempt was to integrate twice the equation above:

$$ \frac{d y}{dt}=-a_1y+\int(-a_2y+a_2u) dt_1$$
$$ y=\int\Big[-a_1y+\int(-a_2y+a_2u) dt_1\Big]dt_2$$

And therefore here is my diagram (actually done on simulink)

[image]

However the book gives this answer:

[image]

Now I am very confused. Is the book diagram correct? Maybe it is a diagram from a different thing... But it definitely doesn't seem to simulate the equation. It looks like they did it directly inspecting the equation and then putting up the diagram. But I thought my way was the correct one... Can someone help me?

Comment: The book answer is the controller canonical form. It does faithfully represent the system. This is one of several canonical forms, and is, arguably, the easiest to derive.

Comment: @Chu Ok, but is mine also incorrect?

Comment: Do not manipulate the equation ... Use this as it is. Sometimes, reorganize by changing the terms member, not here. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/579890/how-to-build-a-van-der-pol-oscillator/579901#579901

Comment: @GrangerObliviate You could create, in parallel, the solution as you see it and feed them, both, the same input. If the outputs coincide...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Now, it's the same as your original drawing.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer. Can you please explain me why is ot correct in your third/fourth step to reverse the order like that? How does that doesn't change the system behaviour? Thank you!

Comment: The two blocks are in cascade and their respective transfer function multiply. It makes no difference if block X is before block Y to the multiplication; the overall transfer function is the same @GrangerObliviate